# Python. Asyncio - порядок завершения работы корутин

Tags: python, asyncio, task, async-await

Такой код

```
import asyncio
import time

async def nested():
    print(f'   start nested {int(time.time()-t0)}')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(f'   finsih nested {int(time.time()-t0)}')


async def main():
    print(f'start main {int(time.time()-t0)}')
    task = asyncio.create_task(nested())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await task
    print(f'finish main {int(time.time()-t0)}')

t0=time.time()
asyncio.run(main())
```

Ожидаю, что корутина main завершится раньше, чем nested. На деле результат такой

```
start main 0
   start nested 0
   finsih nested 2
finish main 2
```

Можно ли написать код, чтобы main завершилась раньше, чем nested ?

Comment: Зависит от того, насколько можно менять код. Если убрать `await task`, то main перестанет ждать nested, но сразу по окончанию main завершится asyncio.run и скрипт завершится и nested перестанет существовать. Но можно предотвратить завершение.

Comment: Я закоментил await task. В результате main завершился, как ожидал через 1 секунду. Но nested не завершился совсем - как Вы пишите - перестал существовать. Как предотвратить завершение nested после завершения main ?

Comment: Писать в развернутом стиле с loop.run_until_complete(main()) + loop.run_forever(). или взять библиотеку aiorun - тогда скрипт никогда не закончится. А вообще цель какая?

Comment: Можно ещё создать дополнительную функцию, в которой уже ожидать окончания `main` и потом окончания `task`, которую для этого возвращать из `main`. И выполнять эту функцию, а не `main`.

Comment: В таком виде результат получен:
t0=time.time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task1 = loop.create_task(main())
task2 = loop.create_task(nested())
group =  asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
return_value = loop.run_until_complete(group)
loop.close()

Из того, что меня не вполне устраивает - запускаются обе корутины одновременно, а желательно одна корутина вызывает другую.
Считаю вопрос решенным. Благодарю всех ответивших.

Comment: Если вы вернёте из `main` создаваемую там `task`, то можно сделать так: `task_main = loop.create_task(main())` `task_nested = asyncio.gather(task_main)` `asyncio.gather(task_nested)` В любом случае вам нужно будет как-то в явном виде подождать окончания обеих функций так или иначе.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же явным образом ждёте завершения `nested` при помощи `await task`. Если убрать эту строку, то всё работает как вы хотите, я пробовал в `Google Colab` (хотя там нужно кое-что подкручивать в `asyncio`, так просто код не работает):

```
start main 0
   start nested 0
finish main 1
   finsih nested 2
```